# How to float the elements based on the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested lists in my DOM. So I am calculating the height, based on height I need to float left the elements from the bottom of my list. But currently it is taking default float left property which starts from top.

```
Expected Output:
Antelope Camel
Bison    Gazelle

Current Output:
Antelope Bison    
Camel    Gazelle
```

Please help me out, it should supports the internet explorer also, else i could have use `column-count` css property.

this is what tried:

JS:

```
var checkHeight = $(".checkHeight").height();
console.log(checkHeight);

if(checkHeight>233){
    $(".checkHeight li.test").css("float","left");
}
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mwv7g1nw/6/)

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more your problem? I can't urderstand you, sorry :(

Comment: I confess I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I believe you are asking how to set a parameter on the css float property, but this is not how it works. When your elements are all floated, they will arrange themselves based on their order in the DOM, there is no "bottom-up" option

Comment: @ Paulie_D : Its not the duplicate of the question you are suspecting. My requirement is completely different from your suspecting question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. You want it to stop being stacked when the parent container has enough height? I actually think this is more to do with width.

```
  var checkHeight = $(".checkHeight").height();
    console.log(checkHeight);

    if(checkHeight>233){
        $(".checkHeight li.test").css("{'float' : 'left',
   'width' : '100px}");
    }
```

You'd also have to set a height for the parent element. Perhaps media queries in css is a better route depending what you are doing.

Sorry if I haven't grasped what you're doing but without a fiddle or pen it's difficult to see what you want to do.